# How to access web application deployed in aws private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

Suppose there is an web application deployed on aws private subnet and assigned private domain local.example.com. how I can access that web application using public domain name public.example.com?

Comment: This sounds like someone's homework or assignment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a load balancer or reverse proxy in the public subnet.